# Wampserver Upgrading issue

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver, smarty3

I recently updated my wampserver 2.0 to wampserver 2.5.

And while i am running the php smarty code i am getting this error.

```
"Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found in 
     C:\wamp\www\livehrm.new\product\common.php on line 63"
```

I think it might be a pear issue of old wampserver.

Please help me

```
//session_start(); 
require_once 'DB.php'; 
$dbHost = $dbconfig['db_hostname']; 
$dsn1[0] = array('type'=>'DB', 'dsnstuff'=>"mysql://$dbUser:$dbPassword@localhost/$dbName"); $dbdsn = "mysql://$dbUser:$dbPassword@$dbHost/$dbName"; 
$db = DB::connect($dbdsn); 
if (DB::isError($db)) { 
   die ($db->getMessage()); 
}
?>
```

Comment: it just means its time to use mysqli or PDO :)

Comment: Provide code of db.php

Comment: //session_start();
require_once 'DB.php';
 $dbHost = $dbconfig['db_hostname'];
$dsn1[0] = array('type'=>'DB', 'dsnstuff'=>"mysql://$dbUser:$dbPassword@localhost/$dbName");
$dbdsn = "mysql://$dbUser:$dbPassword@$dbHost/$dbName";
$db = DB::connect($dbdsn);
if (DB::isError($db)) {
 die ($db->getMessage());
 }
?>

Comment: @ DJ MHA  <?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db="livehrm";
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Database connection error:\n" . mysql_error ());
?>

Comment: It just means that smarty shouldn't be used anymore. :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Update your DB.php with following code

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
$db="livehrm";

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con, $db) or die ("Database connection error:\n" . mysqli_error($con)); 

?>
```

There is not Class found in you provided code of file DB.php. I will update my answer when you send class code of DB

Comment: there is two db files. One is DB.php inside pear and other is db. When i updated db.php with the code provided by you that error("Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO") is gone. Now the only error is  Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found in C:\wamp\www\livehrm.new\product\common.php on line 63". The DB(caps DB.php) is inside the folder pear of old wampserver 2.0. That Pear folder is not included in the new wampserver 2.5. I will again update the code of common.php on the next comment

Comment: require_once 'DB.php';
    $dbHost = $dbconfig['db_hostname'];

 $dsn1[0] = array('type'=>'DB', 'dsnstuff'=>"mysql://$dbUser:$dbPassword@localhost/$dbName");
 // DB::connect will return a PEAR DB object on success
 // or an PEAR DB Error object on error

 //Lets get to the database
 $dbdsn = "mysql://$dbUser:$dbPassword@$dbHost/$dbName";
 $db = DB::connect($dbdsn);

 // Check if a valid connection is returned
 if (DB::isError($db)) {
 
  die ($db->getMessage());
 }

Comment: i will also update the old DB.php of my old wampserver2.0 on the next comment

Comment: here iam not able to provide the full code. can u share any email or other contact info of you so that i can send the picture of the code

Comment: The class DB which they mention not found is inside the PEAR folder of old wampserver 2.0. The particular pear folder is not included in the new wampserver 2.5 by default

Comment: @user3296248 My Facebook account is shared in my profile. Please view my profile for it.

Comment: i have send you the list of files through facebook.

Comment: @user3296248 Yes I got you message. Pear in not include in new version of WampServer. Here is manual of installation instructions to install pear [link](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php)

Comment: @ DJ MHA i will check on the link man and i will update you if the issue is resolved. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Its not the prefered solution, but this should get you working again.

I strongly recommend that you do in fact convert your code from using the mysql_* extension ot use either the mysqli_* or PDO instead as eventually this approach will not work as the developers of PHP will actually no longer provide the mysql_* extension.

But you can remove the warning messages by changing your php.ini configuration like this :-

Edit `php.ini`

Find this line

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

and change it to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Or you can just add this PHP code at the top of your `db.php`script if you dont have access to your php.ini file

```
error_reporting( E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED );
```

If you are using Virtual Hosts you can actually add this to the specific VH for the site that is still using the old `mysql_*` extension therefore not affecting other site you may be developing/maintaining

Unfortunately in a VH definition you have to use an integer value.

```
<VirtualHost....>
   . . .

   php_value error_reporting 24575
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I updated my db.php(small db) with mysqli and the issue is resolved. But my main error after updating wampserver to 2.5 from 2.0 is"Class 'DB' not found in C:\wamp\www\livehrm.new\product\common.php on line 63". The DB(caps DB.php) is inside the folder pear of old wampserver 2.0. That Pear folder is not included in the new wampserver 2.5. So please help me sir. I will be send you the  code if you share me your details.

Comment: PEAR does not come as part of any PHP installation, you have to install it yourself. Do a google search there are lots of tutorials out there, some are even quite good. Or ask another question specific to Installing PEAR on WAMPServer